# Why is Oracle losing data during commit?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a fairly standard SQL Query as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_NAME;
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME 
(
UPRN,
SAO_START_NUMBER,
SAO_START_SUFFIX,
SAO_END_NUMBER,
SAO_END_SUFFIX,
SAO_TEXT,
PAO_START_NUMBER,
PAO_START_SUFFIX,
PAO_END_NUMBER,
PAO_END_SUFFIX,
PAO_TEXT,
STREET_DESCRIPTOR,
TOWN_NAME,
POSTCODE,
XY_COORD,
EASTING,
NORTHING,
ADDRESS
)
SELECT  
BASIC_LAND_AND_PROPERTY_UNIT.UPRN, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.SAO_START_NUMBER AS SAO_START_NUMBER, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.SAO_START_SUFFIX AS SAO_START_SUFFIX, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.SAO_END_NUMBER AS SAO_END_NUMBER, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.SAO_END_SUFFIX AS SAO_END_SUFFIX, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.SAO_TEXT AS SAO_TEXT, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.PAO_START_NUMBER AS PAO_START_NUMBER, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.PAO_START_SUFFIX AS PAO_START_SUFFIX, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.PAO_END_NUMBER AS PAO_END_NUMBER, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.PAO_END_SUFFIX AS PAO_END_SUFFIX, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.PAO_TEXT AS PAO_TEXT, 
STREET_DESCRIPTOR.STREET_DESCRIPTOR AS STREET_DESCRIPTOR, 
STREET_DESCRIPTOR.TOWN_NAME AS TOWN_NAME, 
LAND_AND_PROPERTY_IDENTIFIER.POSTCODE AS POSTCODE, 
BASIC_LAND_AND_PROPERTY_UNIT.GEOMETRY AS XY_COORD, 
BASIC_LAND_AND_PROPERTY_UNIT.X_COORDINATE AS EASTING, 
BASIC_LAND_AND_PROPERTY_UNIT.Y_COORDINATE AS NORTHING,
decode(SAO_START_NUMBER,null,null,SAO_START_NUMBER||SAO_START_SUFFIX||' ')
||decode(SAO_END_NUMBER,null,null,SAO_END_NUMBER||SAO_END_SUFFIX||' ')
||decode(SAO_TEXT,null,null,SAO_TEXT||' ')
||decode(PAO_START_NUMBER,null,null,PAO_START_NUMBER||PAO_START_SUFFIX||' ')
||decode(PAO_END_NUMBER,null,null,PAO_END_NUMBER||PAO_END_SUFFIX||' ')
||decode(PAO_TEXT,null,null,'STREET RECORD',null,PAO_TEXT||' ')
||decode(STREET_DESCRIPTOR,null,null,STREET_DESCRIPTOR||' ')
||decode(POST_TOWN,null,null,POST_TOWN||' ')
||Decode(Postcode,Null,Null,Postcode)  As Address 
From (Land_And_Property_Identifier
      Inner Join Basic_Land_And_Property_Unit
        On Land_And_Property_Identifier.Uprn = Basic_Land_And_Property_Unit.Uprn)  
Inner Join Street_Descriptor
  On Land_And_Property_Identifier.Usrn = Street_Descriptor.Usrn
Where Land_And_Property_Identifier.Postally_Addressable='Y';
```

If I run this query in SQL Developer, it runs fine with 1.8million features inserted (`select count(*) from TABLE_NAME` within the session confirms this).

But when I run the commit, the data disappears! `select count(*) from TABLE_NAME` now returns 0 results.

We've done a number of things to try and see what's going on:

- During the `Truncate`, tablespace is freed up, and during the insert its filled again. There is no change during the commit. This implies the data is in the database.
- If I do the exact same query but with `and rownum < 100` appended to the end, the commit works. Same with `1000`.
- I found this question: [oracle commit kills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867167/oracle-commit-kills) and had our DBA try the "SQL Trace". This produced a >4GB file which when parsed with TKPROF produced a 120 page report but we don't know how to read it and there's nothing obviously wrong in there.
- Our error logs have nothing in them. And obviously no error during the commit itself.
- There's a trigger/sequence which does increment by 1.8million during the process.

I've repeated this about 4 times now, but the result is always the same.

So my question is simple - what's happening to the data during the commit? How can we find out? Thanks.

Note: This has run fine in the past so I don't believe there's anything wrong with the SQL per-se.

---

Edit: **Issue resolved** by recreating the table from scratch. Now when I insert it only takes 500 seconds compared to the previous 2000. And commiting is instantaneous; when it was broken the commit took 4000 seconds!
I still have no idea why it happened though.

---

For those asking, the Create Table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
(
ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(4000),
UPRN                                               NUMBER(12),
SAO_START_NUMBER                                   NUMBER(4),
SAO_START_SUFFIX                                   VARCHAR2(1),
SAO_END_NUMBER                                     NUMBER(4),
SAO_END_SUFFIX                                     VARCHAR2(1),
SAO_TEXT                                           VARCHAR2(90),
PAO_START_NUMBER                                   NUMBER(4),
PAO_START_SUFFIX                                   VARCHAR2(1),
PAO_END_NUMBER                                     NUMBER(4),
PAO_END_SUFFIX                                     VARCHAR2(1),
PAO_TEXT                                           VARCHAR2(90),
STREET_DESCRIPTOR                                  VARCHAR2(100),
TOWN_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(30),
POSTCODE                                           VARCHAR2(8),
XY_COORD                                           MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY,
EASTING                                            NUMBER(7),
NORTHING                                           NUMBER(7)
)

CREATE INDEX TABLE_NAME_ADD_IDX ON TABLE_NAME (ADDRESS);
```

Comment: :Check for the script of your table ,may be its a Global temporary table ,which truncate the data on commit .`http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/temporary-tables.php`

Comment: Do you have constraints on the table (especially deferred constraints)? Do you have on-commit materialized view defined? These are the only thing I can think of that could make a commit fail (although in any case you should get an error message).

Comment: @GauravSoni - Thanks for the suggestion. It was created as a regular table with a normal "create" in SQL Developer. Syntax: `CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( ... some columns ... )`

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - I'm not an Oracle type so don't know what they are. As just noted in my other message, to the best of my knowledge it should just be a regular table. I haven't tried deleting the table and recreating it. I think that's next.

Comment: Can you try the same in sqlplus and see what happens.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan See the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720049/oracle-sql-developer-tool-data-not-available-after-commit

Comment: @Polppan - Thanks for that. I'm 99% certain its not a temporary (we have the create syntax in a text file), but have recreated the table and am going to try again.

Comment: Can you post the "create syntax in a text file" that you have? Are you getting any error and if so, which? Can you post the output of "select * from user_tables where table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'"?

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with `XY_COORD MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY`.  If you generate a trace file for any truncate, or perhaps any DDL, you'll see a large PL/SQL block that's checking something related to MDSYS, SDO, etc.  I have no idea what it's doing, but it looks like lousy code.

Comment: @jonearles - I'm inclined to think it relates to the spatial column too. Probably the Spatial Indexes specifically. Bit rubbish of Oracle to "lose" data without erroring though.

Comment: Could it have been that the old table had one or more triggers defined on it? That may also explain the improved performance with the recreated table.

Comment: Are you sure the COUNT(*) function has not overflown with the number of rows in the table? There is a certain limit to this function on how big a number it can return.

Comment: @YogeshR - There are only a few million rows. And that doesn't explain why the data wasn't in the database when I explicitly queried it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it was a GTT (Global Temp Table). A GTT is also created using the `CREATE` command like `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_name(....) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;` . The `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` will delete anything that was inserted when a `COMMIT` is issued.

Comment: @Rachcha: `count()` doesn't *overflow*

Answer (score 1):

Do you still lose the data if you wrap the transaction in an anonymous block?

My guess is that you are opening two SQL windows in SQL Developer and that means two separate sessions.  i.e. Running SQL code in window 1 and doing commit; in window 2 will not commit changes done in window 1.

Truncate table does an implicit commit. So the table will be empty until insert + commit finishes.

```
begin
  execute immediate 'truncate table table_name reuse storage'; --use "reuse" if you know the data will be of similar size
  -- implicit commit has occured and the table is empty for all sessions
  insert into table_name (lots)
     select lots from table2;
  commit;
end;
```

You should use truncate with reuse storage, so that the database doesn't go a free all the blocks just to acquire the same number of blocks in the insert.

If you want/need to have the data available at all times a better (but longer) method is

```
begin
   savepoint letsgo;
   delete from table_name;
   insert into table_name (lots)
   select lots from table2;
   commit;
exception
   when others then
      rollback to letsgo;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably you had a trigger which you didn't noticed. Can you check the oracle's recyclebin table which might be storing the history of your dropped table and trigger?

```
Select * from recyclebin;
```

References : http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/recyclebinflashback.html